# Accessing first item in $resource.query() - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, express, pug

I'm having some problems with the $resource.query() method. I'm trying to access the first element in it, but its not working for me. The selection controllers returns the collection without a problem.

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('bookshelf').controller('bsMainCtrl', function($scope, bsBooks){
  var data = bsBooks.query();
  $scope.singleBook = data[0];
});

angular.module('bookshelf').controller('bsSelectionCtrl', function($scope, bsBooks){
  var booksData = bsBooks.query();

  $scope.books = booksData;
});
```

**main.jade**

```
.singleBook
  .selection
    include selection
  .content
    include book-list
```

**book-list.jade**

```
div(ng-controller='bsMainCtrl') 
  p Title: {{ singleBook.title }}
  p Author: {{ singleBook.author }}
  p ISBN: {{ singleBook.ISBN }}
  p Created at: {{ singleBook.createdAt | date }}
  a(ng-href='/edit/{{ singleBook._id }}') Edit
```

**selection.jade**

```
div(ng-controller="bsSelectionCtrl")
  div(ng-repeat='book in books')
    button(ng-click='selectBook()') {{ book.title }}
```

**service.js**

```
angular.module('bookshelf').factory('bsBooks', function($resource) {
  var BookshelfResource = $resource('/api/books/:_id', {_id: "@id" }, {
    update: {method: 'PUT', isArray: false}
  });

  return BookshelfResource;
});
```

**route.js**

```
exports.getBooks = function(req, res){
  Book.find({}).exec(function(err, collection){
    res.send(collection);
  });
};
```

Is it Angular $scope related? I have tried using the Angular inspector, but could only conclude that singleBook is null.

Comment: var data = bsBook.query(function(){ var first = data[0]; }) // wait server then assign val.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$resource.query()` returns a promise, which contains no data initially, so you can't access it by numbered index at the point where you're attempting to.

Try instead:

```
bsBooks.query().$promise.then(function(data){
  $scope.singleBook = data[0];  
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YPPqtQP2C0vuPHepkmQ5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use callback or promise for wait data from server

```
var data = bsBook.query(function(){ 
   $scope.singleBook = data[0]; 
})
```

see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

Comment: This is a callback alternative to the promise version I offered in my answer. There is probably no reason for him to assign to a local variable named data, so this might be better presented as `bsBooks.query(function(data){ $scope.singleBook = data[0]; });` where data's value is attained through parameter.